# Going down a chain of documents to retrieve values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, google-cloud-functions

I have a collection of stories, each collection of stories has a collection of chapters and each collection of chapters have a collection of activities.

I'm trying to figure out an easy way to go through the ocllection of stories, chapters and activities and putting them in an equivalently structured json.

So far my code is tsarting to look a bit hectic and I'm struggling to get it to work right:

```
        var toRet:any = {}
        return storiesRef.get()
        .then((stories)=>{

            stories.docs.forEach((story)=>{

                var chaptersRef = story.ref.collection(CHAPTER)
                toRet[story.id] = story.data()

                return chaptersRef.get()
                .then((chapters)=>{
                    chapters.docs.forEach((chapter)=>{

                        toRet[story.id][chapter.id] = chapter.data()

                        var activitiesRef = chapter.ref.collection(ACTIVITY)
                        return activitiesRef.get()
                        .then((activities)=>{
                            activities.docs.forEach(activity => {
                                toRet[story.id][chapter.id][activity.id] = activity.data()
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
```

The code above doesn't work but instead of trying to fix it I feel like I *must* be missing something as my task should be fairly straightforward interms of getting the values I want.

Is there a way to chain the promises together in a way which makes more sense than a deeply nested loop like this?

Comment: having a `return` in a `.forEach` shows a lack of understanding of `.forEach` for a start

Comment: Nesting helps you track your story and chapter context. You are using objects, not arrays, so you can't use array.map. Return statements aren't nec. If you break out the callbacks, you have to pass the param context. I like it as is